# Create a table of EURUSD prices with NAs values

Tags: r

I have a table with the following data:

```
head(EURUSD0)
                 Date   Open   High    Low  Close
1 2005-05-02 00:00:00 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861
2 2005-05-02 00:04:00 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860
3 2005-05-02 00:10:00 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861
4 2005-05-02 00:11:00 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860
5 2005-05-02 00:12:00 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861
6 2005-05-02 00:13:00 1.2862 1.2862 1.2861 1.2861
```

The date is defined as POSIXlt:

```
EURUSD0$Date <- as.POSIXlt(EURUSD0[,1],format = '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
```

I create an empty data frame as follows:

```
startDate = EURUSD0$Date[1]
endDate = EURUSD0$Date[nrow(EURUSD0)]
dateSeq1min = as.POSIXlt(seq(from=startDate, to=endDate, by="1 min"))
EURUSD <- data.frame(Date=dateSeq1min,
               Open=rep(NA,N),
               High=rep(NA,N),
               Low=rep(NA,N),
               Close=rep(NA,N),
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

That is,

```
head(EURUSD)
                 Date Open High Low Close
1 2005-05-02 00:00:00   NA   NA  NA    NA
2 2005-05-02 00:01:00   NA   NA  NA    NA
3 2005-05-02 00:02:00   NA   NA  NA    NA
4 2005-05-02 00:03:00   NA   NA  NA    NA
5 2005-05-02 00:04:00   NA   NA  NA    NA
6 2005-05-02 00:05:00   NA   NA  NA    NA
```

I want to fill this data frame with the information I have in EURUSD0. Note that in EURUSD appear every minute while in EURUSD0 does not.

I am able to do it with a for using this idea:

```
> (EURUSD0$Date[1] == EURUSD$Date)[1:10]
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> (EURUSD0$Date[2] == EURUSD$Date)[1:10]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But I have a lot of data and it is very expensive.

Any idea/hint how to proceed (in a non expensive way)?

Comment: Trying to understand this. So you want your target frame to be mostly NAs, and otherwise just a few values?

Answer (score 3):

One solution using `merge`:

```
merge(EURUSD[1], EURUSD0, by="Date", all.x=T)
                 Date   Open   High    Low  Close
1 2005-05-02 00:00:00 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861
2 2005-05-02 00:01:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
3 2005-05-02 00:02:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
4 2005-05-02 00:03:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
5 2005-05-02 00:04:00 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860
6 2005-05-02 00:05:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

With this approach, a simple data frame with the time values will suffice: `EURUSD <- data.frame(Date=dateSeq1min)`.

---

**Update**

From the documentation for `?POSIXct`:

> "POSIXct" is more convenient for including in data frames, and
>   "POSIXlt" is closer to human-readable forms.

When we try to merge data with different classes we must be careful as the merge will not match exactly. In this case you were trying to merge the first data frame with class "POSIXlt" with the second data frame "POSIXct". They were not an exact match because the timezones are different.

Why was it POSIXct? Because it was coerced to that class when the data frame was created.

To account for that documented behavior we can convert the first data frame to "POSIXct" for matching, then do the merge:

```
EURUSD0$Date <- as.POSIXct(EURUSD0$Date)
merge(EURUSD[1], EURUSD0, by="Date", all.x=T)
#                  Date   Open   High    Low  Close
# 1 2005-05-02 00:00:00 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861 1.2861
# 2 2005-05-02 00:01:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 3 2005-05-02 00:02:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 4 2005-05-02 00:03:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
# 5 2005-05-02 00:04:00 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860 1.2860
# 6 2005-05-02 00:05:00     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Comment: If you feel that it helped you can accept the answer on the left.